# Declined assaulting the Overseer UFO after shooting it down. Any consequences?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I shot down the Overseer UFO with an EMP-fitted Firestorm.

However I did not dispatch the Skyranger, and a after a few days the crash site disappeared.

Will another Overseer eventually appear? Is my game "stuck" because I didn't do that mission?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There will be an endless stream of Overseer UFO encounters until you successfully assault it.  Just wait a couple of days.

Comment: I think, cannonically, they simply repair the ship. There's only ever the one.

Comment: @RavenDreamer you're probably right, I've amended my answer.